# SharePoint Online - How to activate SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

When connecting to the SharePoint online using SPD2013 I receiving a message:

> You do not have permission to open this web site in SharePoint Designer

I signed in using a top level Admin account to office 365 SharePoint Online Admin Center. I notice there no option  such as **Enable SharePoint Designer** and **Custom Script** option.

I tried activating from PS but the connection return a message *Current site is not a tenant administration site.*

> Connect-SPOService -Url https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mydev101 -credential developer@domain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than site permission make sure to install SharePoint Designer SP1 to access SharePoint online.

Comment: Yes, installing SP1 kb is also important. You could mark the reply as answer if it help to resolve the question so that it could also help others in the forum. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the user have a Designer, Owner, or Administrator rights to the target site collection or web site.
2. When activating using Connect-SPOService command, the Admin Center url is like this:

   https://Tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com

   ```
    $AdminSiteURL="https://Crescent-Admin.sharepoint.com"
    $SiteURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/creditpipeline"

    #Connect to SharePoint Online Admin Center
    Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL -Credential (Get-Credential)

    #Enable SharePoint Designer for the site collection
    Set-SPOSite -Identity $SiteURL -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $False
   ```

Reference:

[SharePoint Online: Enable SharePoint Designer using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/09/sharepoint-online-enable-sharepoint-designer-using-powershell.html)